# UILabel position inside UITableViewCell not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to change the position of a UILabel contained inside a custom UITableViewCell, but it doesn't move. I have autolayout enabled.

```
int offset = 0;
if(indexPath.row == 0) {
    offset = 200;

}
if(indexPath.row == [self.treno.fermate count]-1) {
    offset = -200;
}
[self moveLabel:cell.nomeFermata byOffset:offset];
[cell setNeedsLayout];

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
```

And here is the method

```
-(void) moveLabel:(UILabel*) label byOffset:(int) offset {

CGRect frame = label.frame;
frame.origin.y += offset;
NSLog(@"%f",frame.origin.y);
label.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Auto layout probably moved it back. You should wire the top margin constraint to your table view cell class and change the `constant` of the constraint instead.

Comment: When using auto layout, you shouldn't be setting any frames.

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Even I have update the constraint also but it still same position. Can anyone help on this issue